# vtk user class in Python

Tags: python, vtk

I'd like to extend **vtkActor** with my own stuff in Python.
I cannot find the way to call the base class `__init__`, it looks there is no `__init__`.
Maybe the **vtk/Python wrapping** does not allow such a user specialization, the `super` fails saying `vtkActor` is not a type... *hmmm*...

how can I do something like :

```
class MyVtkActor(vtk.vtkActor):
  def __init__(self,*args):
    vtk.vtkActor.__init__(self,*args)
    # my stuff here
```

?

Comment: After Thorsten's answer, I've found this interesting doc: http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Wrapping/Python/README_WRAP.txt

Comment: And now something completely different, how can you set properties to such an object, there is no way to have `MyVtkActor(Object,vtk.vtkActor)`. Do I have to come back to an aggregation instead of a derivation?

Answer (score 3):

The Python-wrappers for VTK-classes are somewhat different. Have a look at this ipython-session:

```
In [1]: import vtk

In [2]: type(vtk.vtkActor)
Out[2]: <type 'vtkclass'>

In [3]: type(vtk.vtkActor())
Out[3]: vtkobject
```

Basically, you can still inherit from vtkActor, but you cannot depend on the object-initialization that is used in Python. You can still call the "normal" methods of this super-class explicitly, with `self` as first argument.

You must set all properties manually that a call to the contructor (in a C-meaning) would do.

Remember: object construction is performed before initialization, so if you inherit from vtkActor, the normal vtkActor constructor is being called. So by defining

```
class MyActor(vtk.vtkActor):
    pass
```

you also get an vtkobject:

```
In [8]: type(MyActor())
Out[9]: vtkobject
```

If you are in need of a real-life sample, you could look at [this class](https://github.com/nipy/PyLocator/blob/master/pylocator/markers.py). It's part of my [PyLocator](http://pylocator.thorstenkranz.de) program. Each marker (blue/green balls on the screenshots) is such an object.

Comment: ok, works great, thanks.    As a matter of fact this is ok because there no arg at all in the `vtkActor` constructor and then the existing Python code was already building first an empty object and then fill it. I'm not a `vtk` coder but looks like most `vtk` constructors are empty ? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you usually first create the objects, the fill its values. If you need to do this often, you should define some kind of factory-function for yourself.